# <Reference Request> Research done on whether the Euler prime can be the largest factor of an odd perfect number

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, open-problem, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196282).)

Good day!

I would like to request for references to research done as to whether the Euler prime of an [odd perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) can also be its largest factor.

To be more specific, the Euler prime $q$ of an odd perfect number $N$ is the *sole* prime factor that occurs to an (odd) exponent $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  That is, we can write this odd perfect number in the form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, where $\gcd(q, n) = 1$.

In an e-mail, it was communicated to me by [Douglas Iannucci](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=26955) that his advisor, [Peter Hagis Jr.](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=26966), considered this possibility.  I was wondering if anybody here knows of any partial results in this direction.

Thank you!

[Added Feb 8 2015] We do know that the Euler prime $q$ is not the smallest prime factor of an odd perfect number $N = {q^k}{n^2}$.  To see why, it suffices to consider:

$$q + 1 = \sigma(q) \mid \sigma(q^k) \mid 2N.$$

Comment: Thank you for the first up-vote!  =)

Comment: Assuming that it is speculated that no odd perfect number exists, why would there be a research on the greatest possible prime factor of such hypothetical (and presumably non-existing) number?

Comment: @barakmanos, since we still do not know whether or not an odd perfect number exists, the logical way to prove that there is none is to show a contradiction from assuming *some* (myriad of) conditions.  Now if it so happens that there *does exist* an odd perfect number (currently known to be at least ${10}^{2000}$), then research on the largest prime factor might shed light on where to look for.  That being said, thank you for your comment... =)

Comment: @barakmanos, if you're still skeptical, I invite you to peruse the papers on odd perfect numbers by Hagis and Iannucci.

Comment: I wasn't being skeptical, it's just that I've always assumed that *odd perfect number* was a relatively negligible issue in the general branch of Perfect Numbers under the field of Number Theory. For example, I would think that a research on *Mersenne Primes* (with which you generate the **even** perfect numbers) was a lot more interesting - are there infinitely many of them, how can we quickly determine the prime factors of a Mersenne numbers (like $2047$ for example), how can we generate the next one, how often do they occur (this one in fact **has been** answered as far as I know), etc.

Comment: Anyways, +1 for the interesting post...

Comment: Actually, knowledge on odd perfect numbers can *potentially* yield information about even perfect numbers (and vice-versa).  To see the connection, I humbly invite you to check out [Euclid-Euler Heuristics for (Odd) Perfect Numbers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5616).